# How do I remove the word 'Appendix' in the title of my appendix

Tags: appendix

How do I remove the word "Appendix" in "Appendix A"? Or, what can I do so that my lemma just says "Lemma A.1"? All I have used in my code is `\appendix`  followed by `\section{Optimal Values of Weighted Averages}`,  and I have seen many people's LaTeX files not displaying the word "Appendix". Many thanks.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. The behavior you've encountered is not the default behavior for any document class I'm  familiar with. Please tell us which document class you employ, and please reveal whether the preamble of your document modifies the properties of the `\appendix` macro or of the `appendices` environment. Do you load the `appendices` package?

Comment: E.g., is there an instruction such as `\renewcommand\thesection{Appendix\quad\Alph{section}}` somewhere in your code?

Comment: OTOH, if you had provided a complete MWE we could have found what was causing it in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to answer without knowing the class you are using. Everything works fine with the standard `article` class:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}

\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}[section]


\begin{document}

\appendix

\section{Optimal Values of Weighted Averages}

Below, we will prove two lemmas [...]

\begin{lemma}
  Suppose $a \geq b$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$. Then $a \geq a\lambda +
  b(1 - \lambda) \geq b$.
\end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem you have seems to be a wrong modification of `\appendix`. Try with writing

```
\renewcommand{\appendix}{\par
  \setcounter{section}{0}
  \setcounter{subsection}{0}
  \gdef\thesection{\Alph{section}}
}
```

Comment: Wow, ok. I added the last piece of code and it just worked. Thank you :)